# Using a user input to make an object in Java

Tags: object, java.util.scanner

Is there a way for me to take a string input from scanner and create a new object with that string entry? Such as:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is your name: ");
    String name = input.nextLine();
    ListOfNames name = new ListOfNames();
}
```

Note that in the last line the "ListOfNames name = new ListOfNames();" I want the new object to be the string that the variable "name" holds.

I want to do this so that after the object is made I can add it to an array then be able to search the array later after inputting multiple names in for the one I need.

There is probably a way to do this with the arrays class but I am new and unfimliar with the class. Any help would be fantastic! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do...

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> listOfNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is your name: ");
    String name = input.nextLine();
    listOfNames.add(name);
}
```

Just add the received input from Scanner to listOfNames array list.

Or if you are really need to use another Object...

```
public class Name {
   String value;
   public Name(String value) {
       this.value = value;
   }
}

    public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Name> listOfNames = new ArrayList<Name>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is your name: ");
        String nameValue = input.nextLine();
        Name n = new Name(nameValue);
        listOfNames.add(n);
    }
```

Comment: So the second option, the second to last line, what exactly is happening? isn't the object being created "n" and not the "nameValue"? The reason I ask is because I am attempting to make a lending library, so that a person puts in a new media (ex Halo 3) I would want them to input Halo 3 then have that save as a new object so I can change its format and whether who it was loaned to with other methods. So I would need to be able to search the array for the Halo object and then be able to access its details from other methods. Does that makes sense>

Comment: N is just a Name object with a nameField value of the input value. When ever you just search the array of Objects, just specify you are looking for an object with nameField of the given input. 

But if name (string value) is the only thing, then it is probably best to just use String

Comment: How would you go about searching for just the nameField? Sorry I am struggling over here. Thanks for all your help so far!